# Loop in plpgsql halts with no error message only when executed from java

Tags: java, postgresql, loops, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1

I have a plpgsql script <sup>(editor's note: it's a function, actually)</sup> that contains a loop which drops the primary key constraint for some tables that were generated by eclipse-link. It looks something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remove_tables_constraints()
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    constraint_statment text;
  BEGIN
    FOR constraint_statment IN
      SELECT  'ALTER TABLE '||nspname||'.'||relname||' DROP CONSTRAINT '||conname
         FROM pg_constraint
         INNER JOIN pg_class ON conrelid=pg_class.oid
         INNER JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid=pg_class.relnamespace
         where relname not in('exclude_table')
         ORDER BY CASE WHEN contype='f' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,contype,nspname,relname,conname     LOOP
         raise notice 'remove_tables_constraints run [%]', constraint_statment;
         EXECUTE constraint_statment;
     END LOOP;
    RETURN true;
  END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE COST 100;

select remove_tables_constraints();
```

The script is executed using:

```
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
st.execute(scriptStringloadedFromFile);
```

The script worked (and under some circumstances still works) fine.
It stopped working after changing the primary key of the tables from an `int` to a `uid`. The loop halts in mid execution without displaying any error messages (debug is set to the finest level).

The weird part is that the script does work, even after the change, if I just paste it into the psql shell instead of executing it from code. Moreover, it works when executing it from the java code if I unpack the loop and just write all the statements that the loop performs inline.

I've spent a couple of days on this and I'm clueless as to how to continue. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of problems:

- You [*need* to sanitize identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) or you can get exceptions or worse, open an [attack path for SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). Identifiers *can* be illegal strings unless double-quoted. There are several ways to let Postgres take care of that automatically.
  I used two forms below:

  - [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) with `%I` parameter conversion (Postgres 9.1+)
  - Let Postgres coerce a [`regclass`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html) type, [which is even better for *table* names (IMO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349).
- You function is dropping *all* constraints, while you only want to drop PK constraints [(`contype = 'p'`)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-constraint.html) according to your description.
- You are not excluding the system catalog and other system schemas. This should fail, no matter what.
- Do *not* quote the language name `plpgsql`. It's an identifier.

Everything put together it could look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remove_tables_constraints()
  RETURNS boolean AS
$func$
DECLARE
   constraint_statment text;
BEGIN
   FOR constraint_statment IN
      SELECT format('ALTER TABLE %s DROP CONSTRAINT %I'
                    , c.oid::regclass, o.conname)
      FROM   pg_constraint o
      JOIN   pg_class      c ON c.oid = o.conrelid
      JOIN   pg_namespace  n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace 
      WHERE  c.relname <> 'exclude_table'       -- just one? then <>
      AND    o.contype = 'p'                    -- only pk constraints
      AND    n.nspname NOT LIKE 'pg%'           -- exclude system schemas!
      AND    n.nspname <> 'information_schema'  -- exclude information schema!
      ORDER  BY n.nspname, c.relname, o.conname -- commented irrelevant item
    LOOP
         RAISE NOTICE 'remove_table_constraints run [%]', constraint_statment;
         EXECUTE constraint_statment;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN TRUE;
END
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or maybe better, without loop. Here, I first aggregate into a single list of commands and execute that once:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remove_tables_constraints()
  RETURNS boolean AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _sql text;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO _sql
          string_agg(format('ALTER TABLE %s DROP CONSTRAINT %I'
                    , sub.tbl, sub.conname), E';\n')
   FROM (
      SELECT c.oid::regclass AS tbl, o.conname
      FROM   pg_constraint o
      JOIN   pg_class      c ON c.oid = o.conrelid
      JOIN   pg_namespace  n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace 
      WHERE  c.relname <> 'exclude_table'       -- just one? then <>
      AND    o.contype = 'p'                    -- only pk constraints
      AND    n.nspname NOT LIKE 'pg%'           -- exclude system schemas!
      AND    n.nspname <> 'information_schema'  -- exclude information schema!
      ORDER  BY n.nspname, c.relname, o.conname -- commented irrelevant item
      LIMIT 10
      ) sub;

   RAISE NOTICE E'remove_table_constraints:\n%', _sql;
   EXECUTE _sql;

   RETURN TRUE;
END
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: while i very much appreciate the input, my problem is that the function (which may be not optimal but is valid psql) works fine when executed directly from a psql shell but hangs when i try to execute it through java code, i will deal with all other issues once i get it to run.

Comment: @yurib: "*hangs when execute through java code*" sounds like it's waiting for a lock. Check `pg_stat_activity` and `pg_locks`